# Ejecutar makemigrations y migrate desde fichero.py en Python

Tags: python, django

estoy realizando una aplicación en Django, pero quisiera que al momento de comenzar el primer uso de la aplicacion el usuario tenga la oportunidad de generar las tablas el mismo, en la base de datos ya establecida. mi pregunta es si se puede ejecutar los comando "makemigrations y migrate " desde un script en python.

En espera de su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

si se puede; dependiendo del sistema operativo debes importar el archivo de forma dinámica en mi caso yo hago esto:

```
import os
os.system("D:\xxx1\xxx2XMLnew\otr.bat")
```

esta es la documentacion relacionada: [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

luego en tu archivo bat colocas todos los comandos a ejecutar.

Comment: Es una buena opción pero si se quiere tener control de la salida de datos se puede usar el módulo `subprocess`

Comment: @Christian bueno la pregunta es si puede ejecutar los comando ; no pregunto nada sobre interactividad con la salida XD; pero si es buena idea... deberías agregarla como respuesta... tambien y te doy tu like

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent estoy utilizando la solución que me distes pero cuando trato ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error **make() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given** me imagino que me debe de estar faltando algo aqui te dejo el codigo. `def make():
  
   os.system("D:\makemigrations.bat")`

Comment: eso es un error del contenido del script archivo??? o de python???

Comment: ya veo; y donde lo llamas??? le estas pasando algún argumento?; entonces pero no lo estas recibiendo ...

Comment: lo llamo desde un template desde una url, se que le falta un argumento pero no se cual es, si me puedes aconsejar una forma mejor de hacerlo, se lo agradeceria

Comment: def make() no tiene argumento en algun lugar llamas a make(Argumento); solo debes quitarle el argumento ...

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres algo más robusto puedes usar el módulo `subprocess` y sus distintas funciones para iniciar procesos. En este caso haré algo sencillo con `Popen`

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['ruta_de_archivo_a_ejecutar'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Con esto podrás ejecutar otro script y a su vez tener control de la salida, también puedes agregar argumentos a la ejecución del script y eso lo haces agregando los argumentos a la lista que se le pasa a `Popen`